# Creating a label using NSTextField is blurry

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

I'm trying to create a label programmatically using NSTextField, but it comes out blurry: [screenshot](http://img146.imageshack.us/img146/5813/blurryitems.png)

This is my code so far:

```
NSTextfield *textfield = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(5,5,150,20)];
[texField setStringValue:@"some text here"];
[textField setEditable:NO];
[textField setSelectable:NO];
[textField setBordered:NO]
[textField setDrawsBackground:NO]
```

I've traced the problem down to the setDrawsBackground line. I've also tried using [textField setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor] as well, but no luck.

By the way, I've adding to a textField to the subview of a view that is a subview of a scrollview. I've also playing with isOpaque on all the view levels, but no luck there again.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's some additional useful information to be found [in this blog post](http://waffle.wootest.net/2010/09/16/setdrawsbackground-nstextfield-calayer/), which comes from roughly the same time period as this original question. My own problem was solved by force drawing a solid background behind my NSTextField label (using "DrawBackground" with a color didn't work).

Comment: The blog link is 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was my first time subclassing NSView, I had put the above code in the *drawRect* method instead of the *initWithFrame* method. I did this because I was following one of the sample applications from Apple's Dev site.

This was also causing my CPU usage to spike when I was scrolling

Answer (score 9):

If you have no background (including clear) and your text is a subview of any layer-backed superview (you've turned on "wants layer" in code or in IB to allow animations/transitions), you'll get blurry text. You have to choose either no layer backed view or a label with a solid background color.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I originally thought of that, but I was hoping to find a better solution. I tried setting wantsLayer to NO on the views, but still no luck.

Comment: I've never seen this problem caused by anything other than -wantsLayers being YES. Are you sure you've climbed the entire view hierarchy and made sure it was all turned off? How did you do this, in IB or in code? If in code, where/how?

Comment: I'm doing this all through code. I have the following view setup:
-NSScrollView which contains NSView 1.
-NSView 1 contains NSView 2
-NSView 2 is where I have the NSTextField in
Are you saying to set wantsLayer to YES on all view levels?

Comment: I just tried setting wantsLayer:NO on all three levels, same results. Now my scrollview is also contained in a split view, should it also be set on that?

Comment: Are you sure that object is there only once? It looks to me like there are multiple copies stacked atop each other. Just an idea....

Comment: Warren Burton: That was my thought as well—it looks double-struck, not blurred. IEb: Have you checked whether your create-and-add-a-text-field code is being run only once or multiple times? I suspect it's the latter: You're calling it more than once and so adding a two or more text fields in a stack.

Comment: You guys got it. It was the fact that the text was being redrawn constantly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but I have solved it by:

```
textfield.canDrawSubviewsIntoLayer = true
```

Comment: Solved the problem for me. Excellent answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're setting the frame of your `NSTextField` to something with all **integer values**.

Use `roundf()` if necessary.

I was getting a blurry `NSTextField`, and neither adding a solid background nor removing Core Animation layers from my view hierarchy were options for me. I noticed I was setting the frame of this text field to something with a Y value of 4.5, so the following changes fixed the issue for me:

Blurry label:

```
_label.frame = NSOffsetRect(_labelFrame,
                            -0.5 * (someRect.size.width + someConstant),
                            0.0);
```

No blur:

```
_label.frame = NSOffsetRect(_labelFrame,
                            roundf(-0.5 * (someRect.size.width + someConstant)),
                            0.0);
```

(In the above examples, `_labelFrame` and `someRect` are `NSRect`s, and `someConstant` is a `CGFloat`. As you can see, the calculation I was doing in the second line of the first example was passing a non-integer value to `NSOffsetRect`).

Comment: or use .rounded() if you use CGFloat
```let backView = NSView(frame: CGRect(x: (window.frame.size.width/2 - 150).rounded(), y:(window.frame.size.height/2-150).rounded(), width: 300, height: 300))```

Comment: The function `NSIntegralRect` is designed to do this, see: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1391136-nsintegralrect

Answer (score 0):

If you created it via an XIB and it is blurry, I found the fix:

```
[textField setStringValue:@""];
```

If I comment this out it goes blurry; if put back it's crystal clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below:

```
textField.drawsBackground = true
textField.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.withAlphaComponent(.leastNormalMagnitude)
```

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, but worth to mention. I have wasted by entire day debugging the issue. I am using a non-apple external monitor and this is where the issue is identified. Once i open the app in Mac book pro, it is perfectly fine.
So, the Samsung monitor which i am using might be non-retina.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, add

```
CanDrawConcurrently = true
```

property from InterfaceBuilder