# Poor font rendering (Cocoa - Mac)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've noticed a strange and very noticeable difference in font rendering in my xib and my final program, I've attached screenshots below:

[See here for zoomed out image](http://cl.ly/image/0Q3W1H0z1w46)

[See here for zoomed in](http://cl.ly/image/0I3f34143f3C)

What is going on here and how can I make my app font look like it does in XCode? (Does it have something to do with subpixel rendering???).

Comment: Are you drawing the strings yourself or are those NSTextFields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I stole this answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917871/creating-a-label-using-nstextfield-is-blurry):

> If you have no background (including clear) and your text is a subview
>   of any layer-backed superview (you've turned on "wants layer" in code
>   or in IB to allow animations/transitions), you'll get blurry text. You
>   have to choose either no layer backed view or a label with a solid
>   background color.