# Font change on selecting NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsattributedstring, nstextfield

I am wanting to create a simple label with an attributed string. I do this like this:

```
NSDictionary *noNotificationsAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:centredStyle,
                                      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                      [NSFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Bold" size:30],
                                      NSFontAttributeName,
                                      _grey,
                                      NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                      nil];
NSMutableAttributedString *noNotificationsString =
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"No Notifications"
                                       attributes:noNotificationsAttrs];

NSTextField* title_field = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:
                             CGRectMake(
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        200,
                                        200
                                        )
                             ];
[title_field setWantsLayer:true];
[title_field setSelectable:YES];
[title_field setAllowsEditingTextAttributes:true];
[title_field setAttributedStringValue:noNotificationsString];
[title_field setEditable:false];
[title_field setBordered:false];
title_field.tag = 1;
```

Which turns out like this:

[image]

and

[image]

Unfortunately when clicking (selecting) this label it appears like this:

[image]

and

[image]

Which is a bit bolder and pixelated around the corners. This is happening with lots of other labels with different strings, sizes and colours. How can I fix it?!

Please note these labels are nested inside `nsscrollview` -> `nstableview` -> `viewForTableColumn`

---

## Stack on selection:

[image]
I believe the problem is that NSCell calls an edit function on mousedown.

---

The font is also different on selection!!
[image]

---

## Edit:

Interestingly if I remove `wantslayer:YES` from the (2) parent view it does not do this. But they both need wantslayer or else I can't have curved corners etc...

Comment: You can fix it by not setting the background to `clearColor`.

Comment: You are the best. If only you had answered my bounty on another question I wrote! Make sure you write that as an answer.

Comment: No wait. It didn't work... What?! It did for a second.

Comment: agh it sometimes works.

Comment: you have enable user interaction in uilabel??

Comment: this is for MacOS

Comment: Is the background still clear?

Comment: yes!! But still only kinda works. See my answer which kind of works.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. What is `centredStyle`? Can you reproduce it using a font which is included in macOS?

Comment: @Willeke yes get the same thing. If you have time please see my repo https://github.com/maxisme/notifi

Comment: @Willeke everything is in the appdelegate

Comment: Everything looks fine on my (non retina) Mac. Maybe related: [Creating a label using NSTextField is blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917871/creating-a-label-using-nstextfield-is-blurry)

Comment: You ran the app from github?

Comment: No, I copied `MyButton` and `MyLabel` and changed the font to Copperplate-Bold. I called `setOpaque:NO` and `setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]` on my window, it looks weird.

Comment: Yeah I think it must be the nsscroll render

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your code.

```
NSTextView *textEditor = (NSTextView *)[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] fieldEditor:YES forObject:title_field];

[textEditor setSelectedTextAttributes:noNotificationsAttrs];
```

Thus adding the attributes to NSTextView associated with window while selection.

**What you're getting now like bold and font changes after selection will get overrided.**

Edit:

### Working code

Have changed `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` to `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`
and `_grey` to `[NSColor clearColor]`

```
NSDictionary *noNotificationsAttrs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:centredStyle,
                                      NSParagraphStyleAttributeName,
                                      [NSFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Bold" size:30],
                                      NSFontAttributeName,
                                      [NSColor clearColor],
                                      NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,
                                      nil];
```

Comment: `No visible @interface for 'MyLabel' declares the selector 'setSelectedTextAttributes:'`

Comment: what is `InputWindow`?

Comment: and `InputTextField`?

Comment: still happens :(

Comment: See my comment in the main question to see all the code! I believe it has something more to do with the fact it is nested in an nsscroll

Comment: No unfortunately not!!

Comment: Can u give me the source code. Only the part the problem occurs

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Can you pls join me https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151327/cocoa-app

Answer (score 0):

To fix this I made a custom NSTextField where on select it updates like this:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)a{
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [self setNeedsLayout:YES];
    [self.superview setNeedsLayout:YES];
    [self.superview setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

but still acts funny some times

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour seems to be solved by allowing **editing text attributes**:

```swift
let textField = NSTextField()
textField.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
textField.isSelectable = true
```